# c++ templates: max of all template implementations

Tags: c++, templates

If i've got a template function like

```
template<int n> void x();
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that it should only implement this for the maximum value passed as n?
E.g.

```
x<3>();
x<7>();
x<1>();
```

Gets compiled to

```
x<7>();
x<7>();
x<7>();
```

(The actual calls are spread over many functions and files)
I allready tried some code but i cant think of a solution that does this at compile time.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Thanks for all those comments:

1. Of course I could find out the maximum by hand but this would remove a lot of flexibility
2. I think this could be useful if x<7>() uses resources that could be reused by every x<n>() where n < 7
3. I think I will try something like this:

   ```
   template<int n> x(){
       static_assert(n < current_max);
       return x<current_max>();
   }
   ```

   and specialize x<current_max>(), so i will get noticed if current_max is too small. What do you think of this solution?

Comment: Do you know the max? (Most probably the answer is that you cannot do this, but if you can narrow down the problem by providing some constrains or assumptions a different solution might come up)

Comment: Perhaps there's a solvable XY problem at hand. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: what's the point of using templates if you want them all to be the same

Comment: @chris, I suppose the answer to the solvable XY problem at hand is one of: **"use `std::string`"** or **"use `std::vector`"**.

Comment: `template <int> using x = x_impl<7>`?

Comment: Not directly, no. You can (in C++11) do `template <typename T> constexpr T constmax(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {return lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs;} const int maxval = constmax(3, constmax(7,1) ); template <int n> void private_X(); void X() { private_X<maxval>();}`

Comment: I will upvote the question if I can see a clear use case for the functionality.